# Closing gaps between lines in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I have a bar chart, a selection of which looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to fill in the white spaces between each bar such that the bars become a single uninterrupted color, which would look (roughly) like this:

[image]

This was done manually with the fill tool, but I can't do it for every bar. Is there a technique for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Duplicate the layer
- Make everything but the blue bars transparent in the upper layer:

  - *Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel*
  - Color-select the white, and <kbd>Delete</kbd>
  - Color-select the grey lines, and <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Shift the top layer down by the width of the gaps

[image: result]